# I lost MyBaits parameter

Tags: parameters, mybatis

System architecuture 
NginX - Tomcat7( Spring & MyBatis)

```
<select id="countDeptEmpMember" parameterType="my.model.DeptInfoVo" resultType="int">
    SELECT COUNT(epId) 
      FROM empMemberInfo 
     WHERE deptId = #{deptId}
</select>
```

I passed the orgId by Ajax.
But the deptId was lost.

And the result is '0'.

Could you tell me any reason of losing MyBatis parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add getter for my.model.DeptInfoVo.
or you can specify the param like this:

```
int countDeptEmpMember(@Param(value = "vo") my.model.DeptInfoVo vo);
<select id="countDeptEmpMember" parameterType="my.model.DeptInfoVo" resultType="int">
    SELECT COUNT(epId) 
      FROM empMemberInfo 
     WHERE deptId = #{vo.deptId}
</select>
```